# PYTHON PYGAME Image

Tags: python, image, layout, pygame

Hey i'm just making a small game in python its python 2.7.13 i'm using cause i'm used to its syntax(lol i have a syntax error in a way its to do with TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not function) but i'm taking an image from the same directory and trying to display it on screen just to get the layout of the game but i can't get it to work the error i get is on this line

```
display.blit(floor,(x,y))
```

THE ERROR: 
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "1stgame.py", line 38, in 
        floor(x,y)
      File "1stgame.py", line 25, in floor
     display.blit(floor,(x,y))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not function

> here's the code

```
import pygame

#Start pygame

pygame.init()

#Window/Screen/Display

display_x = 800
display_y = 600
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_x,display_y))
pygame.display.set_caption('Platforms')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Colors

black = (0,0,0)
green = (1,166,17)

#Images

floor = pygame.image.load('rock.jpg')
def floor(x,y):
    display.blit(floor,(x,y))
x = (display_x * 0.45)
y = (display_y * 0.8)

not_dead=True
while not_dead:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type==pygame.QUIT):
            not_dead=False 

    display.fill(black) 
    pygame.draw.rect(display, green, [0,550,800,50])

    floor(x,y)


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
print "Hello"

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You have a syntax error "in a way"? In what way? Either it says `SyntaxError` or it doesn't. When you "can't get it to work," what does it do instead of working? Edit your question into a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not sure its a syntax error but i'm positive it is i updated the post with a bit more detail and the error code. it opens then closes immediatly

Comment: if i comment out everything to do with images(not rectangle) the code works perfect

Comment: "I'm not sure its a syntax error but i'm positive it is" - ___What?___

Comment: fixed it i put Floor as a function and surface math2001 got it right. i see it as a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You just need to read the traceback:

Here's the error:

```
def floor(x,y):
    display.blit(floor,(x,y))
```

When you do `def floor`, you define the function `floor`. So, the value of floor is now a function instead of the surface you set earlier. So, in your function, you're trying to `blit` a function, and not a `Surface`.

You need to change the variable name of either

- the function
- the surface

Comment: Hey is there any way to get the image to repeat

Comment: Yes, change the x/y position, and blit. But, this is not the point of StackOverflow. Find a tuto to learn pygame, otherwise you're going to spend *a lot* of energy, for not much in the end.

Comment: K thanks i'm new to python. thanks for the help and guidance.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to make your code look a bit nicer: https://gist.github.com/math2001/3a6839f9d51a139b26cf2c4ecab02c9f